# OpenCV FindContours Causes stop working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 on VisualStudio V10.0.30319.1 RTMRel trying to compile this sample code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
  int max_thresh = 255;
  RNG rng(12345);

  /// Function header
  void thresh_callback(int, void* );

  /** @function main */
  int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
   VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(0);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,960);
char qq=0;
while(qq!=32)
{
    qq = waitKey(30);
    capture.read(src);
    if(!src.empty())
    imshow("Space",src);
}
 /// Convert image to gray and blur it
 cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
 blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

 /// Create Window
 char* source_window = "Source";
 namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( source_window, src );

 createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
 thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

 waitKey(0);
 return(0);
  }

  /** @function thresh_callback */
  void thresh_callback(int, void* )
  {
 Mat canny_output;
 vector<vector<Point> > contours;
 vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

 /// Detect edges using canny
 Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
 /// Find contours
 findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

 /// Draw contours
 Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
 for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
      Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
      drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
    }

 /// Show in a window
 namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( "Contours", drawing );
  }
```

It's a sample code and should work just find but when I try to run the code just after pressing Space to capture the image the program just crashes and says "Ashkan.exe has stopped working" without any error at all!

I know the problem is with the FindContours line because as i comment that line the program runs just fine.

In debug mode when passing findContours line it says: Unhandled exception at 0x76f2320e in Ashkan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

Does anyone know any possible cause for this problem?!

Comment: Can you debug to see what error message it gives you at near findContours?

Comment: When passing findContours line it says: Unhandled exception at 0x76f2320e in Ashkan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff. @TianyunLing

Comment: please *very carefully* check again, what you're linking. are you mixing release/debug libs ? c runtime==MTD ? code does not look suspicious.

Comment: This code is an example that i just copied
I needed too use findContours and it caused crash in my code so i suspected my own code so i googled and find multiple example of findContours, none of them work! Every time happens the same thing with the codes prooven to be working on other devices so i guess the problem is with my libaries or something like that!
By the way i'm a newbie in openCV :D @berak

Comment: again, code looks proper, so look at other things. (i'm sure  you foul up with linking)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by linking!? How can i find out?! @berak

Comment: such problems occur, if you link a debug build to release libs (or the other way), using the wrong c-runtime, etc.